# Free Codesmith alternatives?

Tags: .net, code-generation, codesmith

Are there any free/open source alternatives to Codesmith that would be comparable in features and generate .NET code?

Comment: If you want a different take on template-based code generators, this tool is free. [www.metadrone.com](http://www.metadrone.com)

Comment: Let's have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035599/is-there-any-freeware-tool-available-which-is-like-codesmith

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i did the same research a few years ago and found **[MyGeneration](http://mygeneration.sourceforge.net/)** to be **very** good.

Comment: MyGeneration is an excellent code generation and templating tool.  Given that its open source as well is a defenite plus.  The underly MyMeta API is useful from within your own applications as well and is very powerful.

Comment: Link to MyGeneration is dead.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your needs, Visual Studio's T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) might be worth a look. Check out [Scott Hanselman's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) for an introduction.

Answer (score 2):

There is a deal where you can get CodeSmith for free (limited time), Check out [plinqo.com](http://plinqo.com/) for more information. Although there are many free and paid alternatives. I think it would be a very wise move for anyone to check out the support options and community behind other Code Generators.

If you go to say a product like My Generation and run into a bug, there is no one to help you but yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Codesmith 2.6 is freeware - http://www.codesmithtools.com/freeware.aspx

There is nothing you can't do with version 2.6 - the later versions simply fix a few minor bugs and add a few bells and whistles.

Comment: It should be noted that this version only works on an older version of Visual Studio (2003 if I remember correctly). Also, it is very buggy and would inexplicably quit working at times. I finally gave up and started coding manually as the templates were useless without working software and troubleshooting took more time than writing the new class.

Answer (score -1):

I just find this tool I am already playing with it and until now it looks very promising: https://moplus.codeplex.com/. You can use it within Visual Studio